# Favourite tags in documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation, user-interface

It'll be a good feature if there would be a set of user favourite tags in the documentation, like there is in main Q&A part of SO, so that the user could directly go to his favourite documentation part without browsing the main page.

Also, maybe make the "Documentation" tab link to a documentation page of a listed tag? Say, a user is watching a list of tagged questions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/TAG and clicks on the "Documentation" button in the line with "Questions" button. He should be redirected to the documentation page on that tag to https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/TAG/topics . In case of multiple tags, either use the most popular tag, the one that has documentation, or just skip that and make "Documentation" button to lead on the page with entire docs.